# Transform table to one-hot-encoding of single column value

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table

I have a table with two columns:

```
+---------+--------+
| keyword | color  |
+---------+--------+
| foo     | red    |
| bar     | yellow |
| fobar   | red    |
| baz     | blue   |
| bazbaz  | green  |
+---------+--------+
```

I need to do some kind of one-hot encoding and transform table in PostgreSQL to:

```
+---------+-----+--------+-------+------+
| keyword | red | yellow | green | blue |
+---------+-----+--------+-------+------+
| foo     |   1 |      0 |     0 |    0 |
| bar     |   0 |      1 |     0 |    0 |
| fobar   |   1 |      0 |     0 |    0 |
| baz     |   0 |      0 |     0 |    1 |
| bazbaz  |   0 |      0 |     1 |    0 |
+---------+-----+--------+-------+------+
```

How do I make this transformation in SQL only?

Comment: What does `one-hot encoding` mean?

Comment: Is your list of "colors" known upfront?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes, those four only.

Comment: @Siyual that's the name of transformation, i.e. convert categorical data, to numerical, where each category is in separate column. https://www.quora.com/What-is-one-hot-encoding-and-when-is-it-used-in-data-science

Comment: @Ernest So is it a `bit` or a `count`?

Comment: Then use `CASE WHEN` for each "color".  If `keyword` & `color` pairs are not unique, you will need to add aggregation.

Comment: @PM77-1 thank you the pairs are unique, and your and Oto's solution is what I needed.

Comment: @Siyual a `bit`, 1 for true, 0 for false.

Comment: You could meta-program some non-SQL code to write the SQL code similar to the currently-accepted answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you need conditional aggregation:

```
select keyword,
count(case when color = 'red' then 1 end) as red,
count(case when color = 'yellow' then 1 end) as yellow
-- another colors here
from t
group by keyword
```

Comment: Not sure why it was downvoted, it does exactly the job. Seems so obvious now, thank you.

Comment: This does meet the criteria of the original question, but I'm looking for a way to dynamically one hot encode 100+ columns for a data scientist. It's basically needing to pivot each column's potential values and do it dynamically. Hoping someone would have already written out the dynamic SQL!

Comment: @njkroes, did you ever find an answer to this? I'm running into a similar situation where the list of columns I wish to encode may change

Comment: @njfrazie I ended up just using a bunch of IIF statements to do this as outlined here. In a situation where you are looking a large set of data, you could take all represented answer and dynamically generate something, but there's really no way to do something for one record on the fly unless you already knew what to expect. In that case, you would just write out all expected outcomes like this answer suggests.

Comment: This does not work if you have duplicates. You would end up with numbers greater than 1. First you need to get distinct elements of that class, apply the query above and then join with the original.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve the goal in your test case using [`tablefunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html) extension and [`COALESCE()` to fill all NULL fields](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210885/default-values-for-crosstab-results):

```
postgres=# create table t(keyword varchar,color varchar);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into t values ('foo','red'),('bar','yellow'),('fobar','red'),('baz','blue'),('bazbaz','green');
INSERT 0 5
postgres=# SELECT keyword, COALESCE(red,0) red, 
 COALESCE(blue,0) blue, COALESCE(green,0) green, 
 COALESCE(yellow,0) yellow 
 FROM crosstab(                         
  $$select keyword, color, COALESCE('1',0) as onehot from test01
    group by 1, 2 order by 1, 2$$,
  $$select distinct color from test01 order by 1$$)
 AS result(keyword varchar, blue int, green int, red int, yellow int);
 keyword | red | blue | green | yellow 
---------+-----+------+-------+--------
 bar     |   0 |    0 |     0 |      1
 baz     |   0 |    1 |     0 |      0
 bazbaz  |   0 |    0 |     1 |      0
 fobar   |   1 |    0 |     0 |      0
 foo     |   1 |    0 |     0 |      0
(5 rows)

postgres=#
```

And if you just to obtain the result under `psql`:

```
postgres=# select keyword, color, COALESCE('1',0) as onehot from t
  --group by 1, 2 order by 1, 2
  \crosstabview keyword color
 keyword | red | yellow | blue | green 
---------+-----+--------+------+-------
 foo     |   1 |        |      |      
 bar     |     |      1 |      |      
 fobar   |   1 |        |      |      
 baz     |     |        |    1 |      
 bazbaz  |     |        |      |     1
(5 rows)

postgres=#
```

Answer (score 1):

To use this code on a table with a high number of columns, use Python to generate your queries:

1) Create a list with unique variables that you want to have as your column names and import this to Python, say as: `list`.

```
for item in list:
 print('count(case when item=' +str(item)+ 'then 1 end) as is_'+str(item)+',')
```

2) Copy the output (minus the last comma on the last row)

3) Then:

```
select keyword,

OUTPUT FROM PYTHON

from t
group by keyword
```

Comment: The question asks for a SQL-only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the same thing but programmatically create the cases.
In your example, you have a short list of colours, but if you have many different categories, you can run something like:
(Note: Below code is for SQL Server)

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000;
SET @cases = NULL;

SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
        0xd0a,
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN color = '",
        color,
        "' THEN 1 END) AS ",
        color
    )
    SEPARATOR ','
) INTO @cases
FROM table_name t;


SET @sql = CONCAT(
"SELECT 
t.keyword,",
@cases,
"
FROM table_name t
GROUP BY keyword
"
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: It appears you have posted SQL Server code when the question is tagged "postgresql".

Comment: Ok, sorry, I assumed it would work. The basis contains the same commands. Should I delete the response?

Comment: Do you think your SQL Server code will help people who land on this question - probably because they have a similar problem and are searching for a solution?

Comment: This post helped me to write this code and solve my problem. This is why I felt like contributing. I think it could be useful, and your comment helps to make it less confusing.