# How can I convert an integer array into one hot encoding in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BQ table like this:

```
ID  index
A   [1, 3, 4]   
B   [2]
C   [0, 3]
D   [2, 3]
```

I hope to get a new table with a single one-hot encoded index column with a fixed length:

```
ID  index
A   [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]   
B   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
C   [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
D   [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

There is a similar problem here: [Transform table to one-hot encoding for many rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56058860/transform-table-to-one-hot-encoding-for-many-rows), but that converted into multiple columns instead of a single column.

Answer (score 2):

Use below

```
#standardSQL
with temp as (
  select i from (
    select max(i) as max_index
    from `project.dataset.table` t,
    t.index i
  ), unnest(generate_array(0, max_index)) i
)
select id,  
  ( select array_agg(if(i = i1, 1, 0) order by i)
    from temp 
    left join t.index as i1
    on i = i1
  ) index
from `project.dataset.table` t
```

If apply above to sample data in your question

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 'A' id, [1, 3, 4] index union all
  select 'B', [2] union all
  select 'C', [0, 3] union all
  select 'D', [2, 3] 
)
```

- output is

[image]

As you can see it produces one column - array of integers
In case if you want column to be of string type - use below instead of `array_agg`

```
string_agg(if(i = i1, '1', '0') order by i)
```

in this case output will be (very similar)

[image]